# Loggin middleware with winston and morgan

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs

I create a logger middleware with using winston and morgan like below:

```
  const format = winston.format.combine(
    winston.format.timestamp({ format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss:ms' }),
    winston.format.printf(
      (info) => `${info.timestamp} ${info.level}: ${info.message}`,
    ),
  )

  const transports = [
    new winston.transports.Console(),
    new winston.transports.File({
      filename: 'logs/error.log',
      level: 'error',
    }),
    new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'logs/all.log' }),
  ]

  const logger = winston.createLogger({
    format,
    level: "info",
    transports
  })

  const stream = {
    write: (message) => logger.log(message),
  };

  const morganMiddleware = morgan(
    ":remote-addr :method :url :status :res[content-length] - :response-time ms",
    { stream }
  );

  app.use(morganMiddleware);
```

But when my start is running and receive first log, winston throw me this error:

```
level[LEVEL] = level.level;
                   ^

TypeError: Cannot create property 'Symbol(level)' on string '::1 GET /api/amr/applications?order=ASC&sortBy=application.lastIncidentAt 304 - - 380.459 ms
```

can someone tell me what is wrong with my winston/morgan configuration?

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Winston logger expects two arguments. So instead of this:

```js
const stream = {
  write: (message) => logger.log(message),
};
```

Do this:

```js
const stream = {
  write: (message) => logger.log('info', message),
};
```